# Customers email displays HTML tags on PHP system generated mail

Tags: php, html, email, server, dedicated-server

When I send a really basic HTML email via a file using PHP mail it displays perfectly for me. But for my client he sees all the HTML tags in the email.

I have my own dedicated server, to try to problemsolve I ran the exact same file from a Heart Internet shared server I have and the email displayed perfectly to my client (no HTML tags) so it points to something to do with the server.

```
<?php
$to  = 'tom@myemailaddress.com'; 
$subject = 'TOM Testing: HTML displaying correctly?';

$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>To see if</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>You</th><th>See</th><th>The</th><th>HTML</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>or</td><td>it</td><td>is</td><td>formatted</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>correctrly</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Here is my php info: http://www.saloponline.co.uk/phpinfo.php

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: Shouldn't make any odds but if you're using Postfix as the mail server it expects the line terminators on the headers to be those of the OS your server is running so it's actually better to use `PHP_EOL` rather than "\r\n"

Comment: You should look into sending a multi part email with both Plain text and HTML email. It sounds like your client's email program doesn't read HTML email.

Comment: Hi Owen, my clients email program does read HTML, as stated the exact same file executed on a different server displays the HTML perfectly for him.

Comment: Fixed, I took swapped \r\n for just \n - I guess PHP_EOL would have done the same, thanks CD001